# Can someone else turn on my computer on Shabbat/yom tov using Wake-on-LAN

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Let's say I am not Jewish, and I have a bunch of Jewish people in an apartment building on one big LAN.  During Shabbat I want their computers to all turn on at a specific time so I send a WOL message and turn them on.  None of them directly asked me to do this but they will benefit from the computer being on.  Is there a problem? What if one of them asked me to do this? What about yom tov? What if they said to me, "we would like our computer to be turned on at some point before 9am on Saturday morning", and I could have send the WOL before Shabbat started, but I elected to send it at 8am during Shabbat?

Comment: Or by the same token, what would be the halachah if you walked into their apartments and switched on their computers, without having been asked?

Comment: In what way will they benefit from the computer being on?

Comment: @Tesvov the computer would turn on and automatically play some video they would enjoy watching.

Comment: How is this different from another case where a non-Jew did a melacha on shabbat for the benefit of Jews?